# How to prove that $(1-x)^b$ $_2F_1(a,b;c;x)$ can be approximated to $1-\alpha x$ (with $\alpha \approx 1$) for $x\ll 1$ in this specific case

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, special-functions, approximation-theory, hypergeometric-functions

After multiple plots I noticed that function $h(x)= (1-x)^b$ $_2F_1(a,b;c;x)$ can be approximated to  $1-\alpha x$ (with $\alpha \approx 1$), for $x\ll 1$ (specifically $0<x<0.1$) and $a=(K-1)d$, $b=K$, c=$Kd$; with $K \gg 1$, $K \gg d$ and $d>1$.

In other words, I need to prove that the first derivative of $h(x)$ is constant ($\approx -1$) for $0<x<0.1$, Or equivalently that :$-b(1-x)^{b-1} \, _2F_1(a,b;c;x) + \frac{ab}{c} (1-x)^b  \, _2F_1(a+1,b+1;c+1;x) \approx \text{constant} (\approx -1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first few terms of the Maclaurin series can be obtained explicitly:

$$1-x-{\frac { \left( d-1 \right)  \left( K-1 \right) }{2\,Kd+2}}{x}^{2
}-{\frac { \left( d-1 \right)  \left( d-2 \right)  \left( K-1 \right) 
 \left( K-2 \right) }{ \left( 6\,Kd+6 \right)  \left( Kd+2 \right) }}{
x}^{3}+O \left( {x}^{4} \right) 
$$

The coefficient of $x^2$ is not especially small, but of course on a small
interval around $0$ the $1-x$ dominates.  I guess the question is really about the behaviour as $K \to \infty$ for fixed $x$.

The Maclaurin coefficient of $x^n$ in $h(x)$ is

$$ A_n(K,d) = \sum_{ k=0}^n (-1)^k {K \choose k}  \dfrac{\Gamma(K+n-k) \Gamma(Kd-d+n-k) \Gamma(Kd)}{\Gamma(K) \Gamma(Kd-d) \Gamma(Kd+n-k) (n-k)!}$$

$A_n(K,d)$ is a rational function of $K$ and $d$ where it appears that numerator and denominator both have degree $n-1$ in $K$ for $n \ge 1$.
Thus as $K \to +\infty$, $h(x)$ may be approaching a smooth limit.  In 
fact, it looks to me like

$$ \lim_{K \to \infty} h(x) = \left( \dfrac{x-1}{(1-1/d) x - 1}\right)^d $$

For example, with $d=3$ and $K=20$ the maximum difference between $h(x)$ and $((x-1)/(2x/3-1))^3$ on the interval $(-1,1)$ is about $0.01388$.

Comment: I think you have to use the rising Pochhammer symbol for Hypergeometric functions. In detail, in the first expression you should replace $d-i$ and  $K-i$ by $d+i$ and $K+i$, respectively.

Comment: I'm pretty sure these formulas, which were obtained with the help of Maple, do involve the correct use of Pochhammer symbols.

Comment: Please see eq. (16) in [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html)

Comment: Note that this series is not for the hypergeometric itself, but for $h(x)$ which is $(1-x)^K$ times the hypergeometric.

Comment: Yes, but $(1-x)^b \, _2F_1(a,b;c;x)= \, _2F_1(c-a,b;c;\frac{x}{x-1})$ using Pfaff transformation.

Comment: That's a series in powers of $x/(x-1)$.  And what do you get when you express it as a series in powers of $x$?

Comment: I probably found the answer: $-x$ is an accurate approximation of $\frac{x}{x-1}$ for $0<x<0.1$. Thus, using the Maclaurin series of $_2F_1(a,b;c;-x)$, we get $1-x+... $ which can be approximated to $1-x$ since the coefficient of $x^2$ is $\frac{1}{2}\frac{(d+1)(K+1)}{Kd+1}\approx$ $1+\epsilon$ (with $\epsilon$ very small ) and $x^2 \ll$ $x$..

Comment: Sorry, it's $c-a$ instead of $a$, and $\frac{1+\epsilon}{2}$ instead of $\epsilon$.